# GWT 2: how can I add Button to the CellTable's header?

Tags: java, gwt, header, celltable

My task is to create a table with a control to add the new lines. This typical control should consist of corresponding set of TextEdits and an "add new row" Button.

I use CellTable.

I can create this "adding widget" separately just combing button and necessary fields in some panel, but I want to try to bind it to the table. I want to make it using the CellTable. For this purpose I try to utilize the header of the CellTable. I created a Header and added a EditCellText and ButtonCell. I have two problems:

- The button is not shown. Instead a value returned by getValue() method is shown.
- I dont know how to handle the click on that button.

[1] Finally, the first question is: **how can you add a button into a header of CellTable and how would you process the click on that button?** The button should looks like a button, not just some click area.

[2] Probably there is another way to accomplish my task. **Is it possible to create CellTable where different rows hold different buttons?** I.e. first row holds button "Add", and all other rows hold button "Remove". Can GWT do this?

[3] One more question. At the moment I describe the structure of my CellTable using Java code. I.e. I create and add column and header objects manually while creating the parent widget. **Is it possible to express the structure of my CellTable with XML, i.e. using some mySpecialCellTable.ui.xml file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for displaying a button in your table you can use a ButtonCell:

```
Column<MyObject, String> delete = new Column<MyObject, String>(new ButtonCell()) {

            @Override
            public String getValue(final MyObjectobject object) {
                return "delete";
            }
        };

        delete.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<MyObject, String>() {

            @Override
            public void update(final int index, final MyObjectobject object, final String value) {

                myActivity.delete(object); // to whatever should happen if button is clicked
            }
        });
```

This should answer the second question as well. As far as I know you have to add the columns in you java class. In your uibinder file you can only add the celltable as a whole.

```
<p1:CellTable ui:field="table"></p1:CellTable>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static class BtnHeader extends Header<String>{

    public BtnHeader(ButtonCell cell) {
        super(cell);

    }
     @Override
       public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, NativeEvent nativeEvent)
       {
          int eventType = Event.as(nativeEvent).getTypeInt();
          if (eventType == Event.ONCLICK)
          {
             nativeEvent.preventDefault();
            updateHeader();
          }
       }
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return "Click!";
    }
    protected void updateHeader() {
        // TODO to redefine in a defiant class

    }

 }
```

And in your code

```
BtnHeader header = new BtnHeader(new ButtonCell()){
                @Override
                protected   void updateHeader(){
                    // Actions when clicking button
                }

cTable.addColumn(column, header);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to do the same with a TextInputCell instead of a ButtonCell. How can I adapt the onBrowserEvent method for this ? Cheers, Tim